# C# ASP.NET Page_Error doesn't handle exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

event Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) doesn't handle expection. Exception is handling by Visual Studio.

I tried throw Exception by Page_Load or button but still isn't working. I can't search any information about this problem. In my book is show simple example with Page_Load, Page_Error, Button and according my book this should working. I guess that in Web.config is missing something.

```
    void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Write("Something not yet");
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        Server.ClearError();
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Load event fired");
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

I expect that throwed Exception will be handled by Page_Error, not by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the errors on application (Application_Error) level in global.asax and forward the request to a custom error page.

This SO thread might be good to look at: 
[Exception handling in ASP.NET Webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558314/exception-handling-in-asp-net-webforms)

Comment: This is definitely more suitable method to catch Exception in ASP.NET but in this case I want know what is reason that event Page_Error doesn't handle Exception althouth all books or tutorials say that it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your Page_Error method as protected:

```
protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Write("Something not yet");
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        Server.ClearError();
    }
```

Comment: Still not working. VS is handling Exception, not method. Thanks for trying

Comment: What do you mean by Visual Studio is handling exception? Have you try putting in a breakpoint inside Page_Error handler?

Comment: Okey I've noticed how is working. VS is throwing statement of exception but if i step next line i will jump to event Page_Error. In my understanding VS shouldn't throw statement of exception. Event Page_Error should working as try/catch. Now Is working that exception is throwing of program and next program jump to page_error.

Answer (score 0):

You were throwing a wrong type of exception. Throw `ApplicationException` instead of `Exception`.